# How to identify points with similar color property?

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I am trying to connect points with similar colors and make them a group to show in the plot. A sample data comes in like this -

```
x = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
y = np.array([[0.0, 1.0, 1.4, 3.0, 4.0],
              [1.0, 1.4, 1.9, 2.1, 3.0],
              [0.9, 1.0, 1.4, 3.0, 3.1],
              [0.3, 1.0, 1.4, 3.0, 3.7],
              [0.1, 1.0, 1.4, 3.0, 3.9]])

color = [[1,0,0.02], [0.01,.91,0], [0,1,0], [0,0.04,1], [1,.91,0],
         [0,1,0.01], [0.00,1,0], [1,.91,0], [1,0.01,0], [0,0,1],
         [1,.91,0.00], [0.03,1,0], [0,1,0], [0,0.00,1], [1,0,0],
         [1,.91,0.03], [0.05,1,0], [0,1,0], [0,0.03,1], [1,0,0],
         [1,.91,0.00], [0.01,.91,0], [0,1,0], [0,0.03,1], [1,0,0]]
```

making a scatter plot out of this data looks like this -

```
plt.scatter(np.repeat(x, y.shape[1]), y, s=12, c=color)
plt.plot(x,y,'k',lw=0.7)
```

[image]

I want to make it something like this -
[image]

The idea is to make groups of similar colors. How can I do this in matplotlib?

Comment: how do you want to separate the 2 green lines

Comment: create `(pointXY,color)` tuples, groupby color and sort by X, then plot each group as a line of a color

Comment: They will be just two groups, hence two lines shown in the second diagram.

Comment: they have the same color how do you make 2 lines out of that, maybe they zig-zag with a spacing of 1 or 2 or 3

Comment: in the actual dataset I have more than 2 lines of same color.

Comment: if you give all your points the same color you still want the same lines as shown in the second image

Comment: Yes, that will be a correct assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You can make clusters of colors with [scipy](/questions/tagged/scipy) but then the greens will be linked :

```
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans2
clusters, indexer = kmeans2(color, 4, minit="++") # adjust if needed

d = {}
for ix, iy, idx in zip(np.repeat(x, y.shape[1]), y.flatten(), indexer):
    d.setdefault(tuple(clusters[idx]), []).append([ix, iy])
    
for ic, ixy in d.items():
    plt.plot(*zip(*ixy), lw=0.7, color=ic, marker="o", ms=6)

plt.show();
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: why don't you use a `defaultdict`

Comment: And why not [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) ?

Comment: this is good to some extent, but I needed two separate lines from green points. they should not be connected like how it appears in this answer. every y point in a certain x location is an exclusive member of one continuous line.